# C# Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, casting, nullreferenceexception, gettype

**Hello, I have a problem understanding why this piece of code:**

```
using System;

class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
    }
}


class NameApp
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person me = new Person();
        Object you = new Object();

        me = you as Person;
        //me = (Person) you;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", me.GetType()); //This line throws exception
    }
}
```

**Throws this exception:**

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NameApp.Main() in C:\Users\Nenad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Exercise 11.3\Exercise 11.3\Program.cs:line
 21

Comment: Plenty of people pointing out the obvious - but what did you *expect* `you as Person` to do?

Comment: I was just following tutorial from a book - most likely author misplaced "you" and "me", but there is not info about it in ERRATA, on companion website, so I just wanted to check it here to be sure, just in case that I didn't miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast with the `as` keyword and the cast is not possible it returns `null`.
Then in your case you call `me.GetType()` with `me` being `null` at the moment so an exception is thrown.

If you cast like `(Person) objectOfTypeThatDoesNotExtendPerson` an exception is thrown instantly at the cast.

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
me = you as Person;
```

is failing and assigning null to `me` because you can't cast a base class type object to child class.

[as (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, **if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception**.

You probably want to cast `person` as `object`, since `me` is an `Object`, but `you` is not a person.

Comment: I was just following tutorial from a book - most likely author misplaced "you" and "me", but there is not info about it in ERRATA, on companion website, so I just wanted to check it here to be sure, just in case that I didn't miss something.

Answer (score 2):

This code will always set `me` as null

```
   Object you = new Object();
   me = you as Person;
```

because `Obejct` is *not* person

but person is `object` :

```
object you = new Person();
me = you as Person;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object you = new Object();
me = you as Person;
```

`you` is an object, not a Person so `you as Person` will simply return null.

Answer (score 1):

```
me = you as Person;
```

`me` is `null` if `you` cannot be casted to `Person` (and that's what happening in your situation, because `new Object()` cannot be casted to `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

The as operator returns null if the object was not of the type you requested.

```
me = you as Person;
```

you is an Object, not a Person, so (you as Person) is null and therefore me is null. When you call GetType() on me afterwards, you get a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Person me = new Person();
    Object you = new Object();

    // you as person = null
    me = you as Person;
    //me = (Person) you;

    System.Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", me.GetType()); //This line throws exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Object can not be cast to a Person.
It is a princip of object oriented programming.

Object is a parent class of a Person.
Every class inherits it,

you can cast Person to Object, but cannot cast Object to Person